# The underlying provider failed to open - WPF and Entity FrameWork

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sql-server-2012, connection-string

I registered website on somee.com and had uploaded my database. They provided me connection string below:

```
workstation id=nrcsadb.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=DuaZoya_SQLLogin_1;pwd=passwordhere;data source=nrcsadb.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=nrcsadb
```

Now as i am using Entity FrameWork so i am writing these lines below to connect my destop application to that database on server.

```
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="nrcsaEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/nrcsaEntities.csdl|res://*/nrcsaEntities.ssdl|res://*/nrcsaEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;user=Dua_SQLLogin_1;password=passwordhere;data source=nrcsadb.mssql.somee.com;initial catalog=nrcsadb;integrated security=False;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

This above connection string is generating exception that:
`Main Window The underlying provider failed to open`

How to solve this problem. Can anyone help me.
Thank You !

Comment: Show the code where you create a connection instance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps System.Data.Entity.dll reference is not set
Try using providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: It says: The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.